# Is there any way to calculate the height of the bottom bar that Samsung adds when selecting Swipe gestures/Full screen gestures as Navigation bar?

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy

When selecting gesture navigation in Samsung devices, a small black bar with three thin buttons is added at the bottom as an overlay. I'm taking a screenshot of the screen, and setting that screenshot as background on the next page. The screenshot doesn't seem to be considering the bottom bar, and when setting it as background, it tries to fill the entire screen, causing some stretching. Adding a bottom margin of the same height of the bottom bar, would solve the issue.

Is there any way to calculate that height?

[image]

Comment: No update here?